# Time Machine to NAS, over internet

Tags: network, time-machine, backup, vpn, nas

I have a Synology DiskStation NAS that I use for Time Machine backups on my LAN. I want to be able to back up when I'm away from home. I've tried:

- Connecting via L2TP VPN running on Synology
- Connecting directly to Synology via AFP

Through both of these methods I can mount the Time Machine share in the Finder, and I've confirmed read/write access to the share when connected over the internet.

However, when I've mounted the share over the internet, and try to "Back Up Now," I get a message that it couldn't find the disk. Even though the disk is mounted.

Answer (score 4):

Synology does have [this walk-through](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Backup_Restore/How_to_back_up_files_from_Mac_to_Synology_NAS_with_Time_Machine) for doing what you want to do.

I will mention that (quite some time ago) I used a Synology NAS as a time-machine target disk, and I did get it to work, but found it to be highly error-prone. Not what you want in a backup. Also slow. I'm using a drive with a direct USB3 connection now and am much, much happier with that.

Comment: This doesn't work over the internet.

Comment: Dude you never answered the OP’s question

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a guide to [configuring Time Machine to back up to a cloud server](https://www.bytemark.co.uk/docs/example-setups/time-machine-linux/) which is almost relevant.  And it looks like the DiskStation supports the same [IPSec server setup](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/knowledgebase/DSM/help/VPNCenter/vpn_setup) that I'm recommending, so you might be able to crib some parts from my guide to make it work.

Time Machine over the internet works for me, even over a 1Mbps connection connection.  Though you have to leave your Mac running for a bit longer to make sure each backup completes, so number of completed backups is going to be proportional to that bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a substantial answer, maybe treat it as complementary to [the first answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140613/8546).

I should expect Time Machine over AFP to be relatively reliable with a LAN, relatively unreliable or impossible when limited to a WAN (wide area network).

In the [Time Machine Network Interface Specification (TMNIS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/TimeMachineNetworkInterfaceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html): [Time Machine Server Requirements](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/TimeMachineNetworkInterfaceSpecification/TimeMachineRequirements/TimeMachineRequirements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008951-CH100-SW1). I guess that whilst a server may meet those requirements, an aspect of the WAN will defeat a requirement.

The size of bands, within a sparse bundle disk image, may be ill-suited to AFP over a WAN. And so on.